# Can you add colors that are not included in R's base package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the Hex values for the branding guidelines of an organization I work with.  None of the colors work in R when plotting with ggplot2.

I have searched online and found this pdf file of colors that are available in R, that is how I know the colors below don't work.

http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Color/Chart/ColorChart.pdf

Is there a way to add additional colors to R's base package?

The Hex values are below.  I tried to create a palette labeled tlc.  Thanks!

```
tlc <- c("#BFD089", "#6E4762", "#D9C58D", "#ED7C68","#F0264F")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are using your custom color palette?

Comment: All of these colors are available: `pie(rep(1, 5), col=tlc)`. I don't think the colors are your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
tlc <- c("#BFD089", "#6E4762", "#D9C58D", "#ED7C68","#F0264F")
```

First in base R:

```
palette(tlc)
plot(1:5,1:5,pch=16,cex=3,col=1:5,axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
```

Or alternatively

```
plot(1:5,1:5,pch=16,cex=3,col=tlc[1:5],axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
```

Then in ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw()) ## cosmetic

d <- data.frame(x=1:5,f=factor(1:5))
qplot(x,x,data=d,colour=f,size=I(3))+
     scale_colour_manual(values=tlc,guide="none")
```

Comment: So I ran the code that you shared with me and I get this response:  Error in col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'BFD089'

Comment: that's bizarre.  Are you sure you included the hash `#` at the beginning of the string?  What happens if you cut and paste the code from my answer above into a clean R session?  What are the results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: Never mind. It worked.  Was my problem related to the fact that I wasn't using the palette() function?  I've created palettes before without it (at least I thought I did. Thanks anyways!  It worked!!

Comment: Hard to say without more detailed information about what you were doing.